# iPhone UITableView Sections

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have been programming a UITableView and each cells pushes a new view, All I Want to do is add two new sections one male and one female, first and second voice need to be in the male section and the third voice needs to be in the female section.

```
#import "FirstLevelViewController.h"
#import "SecondLevelViewController.h"
#import "DisclosureDetailController.h"
#import "SecondVoiceController.h"
#import "ThirdVoiceController.h"



@implementation FirstLevelViewController
@synthesize controllers;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    self.title = @"Voices";

    NSMutableArray *male = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    DisclosureDetailController *th = [DisclosureDetailController alloc];
    th.title = @"First Voice";
    [male addObject:th];
    [th release];

    SecondVoiceController *array2 = [SecondVoiceController alloc];
    array2.title = @"Second Voice";
    [male addObject:array2];
    [array2 release];

    ThirdVoiceController *array3 = [ThirdVoiceController alloc];
    array3.title = @"Third Voice";
    [male addObject:array3];
    [array3 release];




    self.controllers = male;
    [male release];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)viewDidUnload {

    self.controllers = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

-(void)dealloc {

    [controllers release];
    [super dealloc];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.controllers count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *FirstLevelCell= @"FirstLevelCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:FirstLevelCell];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:FirstLevelCell] autorelease];
    }
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    SecondLevelViewController *controller = [controllers objectAtIndex:row];
    cell.textLabel.text = controller.title;
    cell.imageView.image = controller.rowImage;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    SecondLevelViewController *nextViewController = [self.controllers
                                                     objectAtIndex:row];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
}
```

All I Want to do is add two new sections one male and one female, first and second voice need to be in the male section and the third voice needs to be in the female section. Please help been stuck on this for a while!

Comment: please use a more descriptive title

Answer (score 24):

The tableView delegate has a method called [numberOfSectionsInTableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/numberOfSectionsInTableView:). Return the number of sections that you want to create.

Then, in the cellForRowAtIndexPath use `indexPath`'s  other property `[indexPath section]` to segregate rows based on sections.

An example

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2; //one male and other female
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    switch(section){
       case 0:
       return [male count];
       break;
       case 1:
       return [female count];
       break;
    }
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {

    static NSString *FirstLevelCell= @"FirstLevelCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:FirstLevelCell];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:FirstLevelCell] autorelease];
    }
     SecondLevelViewController *controller;
    switch([indexPath section]){
       case 0:
       controller = [male objectAtIndex: [indexPath row] ];
       break;
       case 1:
       controller = [female objectAtIndex: [indexPath row] ];
       break;
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = controller.title;
    cell.imageView.image = controller.rowImage;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for the feedback but please could you go into a bit more detail would really appreciate some written code. Thanks, Sam Houghton.

Comment: apple goes into detail: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html

Comment: It gave me lots of errors and said male and female were undeclared identifier

Comment: That is just an example, I wrote it without actually compiling it. male and female should be NSMutable arrays like controllers. If third voice needs to be female, it is better to add it to a array named female.

Comment: and my static NSString FirstLevelCell has also stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

Hows this?

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 2;
}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return # of rows in section;
            break;
        case 1:
            return # of rows in section;
break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that didn't work it just put the first and second voice in the table and the third voice went, and there were still no sections, thanks Sam Houghton