# UITableView Putting array objects into sections

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, sections

Hey guys I need to know who to put these array objects into two separate sections, that means one section for the red cell and another section for the blue cell. Would really appreciate your help been stuck on this all day now. Here is my code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Initialize the array.
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [array addObject:@"Red"];
    [array addObject:@"Blue"];

    self.ViewTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];    
}
```

Comment: you only have one array in your code?

Comment: sorry i meant a different section for each object

Comment: its cus i have no idea how to delete questions on here :L

Comment: AYFKM: "Please may you write the exact code i will need for this to happen thanks."

Comment: Sam - I have merged your two accounts and deleted the duplicate questions. Please DO NOT ask the same question again. Follow by using comments on your question or by editing the question to provide more details about your problem. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of: [iPhone UITableView sections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445666/iphone-uitableview-sections)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 2; // This returns 2 sections
}
```

**Updated:**
 In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
NSInteger section = [IndexPath section];

if  (section == 0)

  // write your code for red here

if  (section == 1)

  // write your code for blue here
```

Comment: that made two sections with the same objects in, I want two sections one with the red object in and one with the blue object in.

Comment: yes ? So you want 2 sections. 1 section should be red, other 1 should be blue right ?

Comment: Yes that is what im looking for

Comment: hey i did this and it just gave me two sections with red and blue in
    NSInteger section = [indexPath section];
    
    if  (section == 0)
        [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Red"];
    
        
        // write your code for red here
        
        
        
        if  (section == 1)
            [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Blue"];

Comment: I did but i dont know what to write in-between the sections

Comment: lol. accepting an answer means, clicking that 'tick' mark near my answer. Well.. wat do you mean by write in-between the sections ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement:

return number of sections:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

return number of rows for the requested section

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

return correct cell by reading both indexPath.row and indexPath.section

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

So for red you would look for a cell request that has indexPath.section equal to 0 and indexPath.row equal to 0.  blue would be indexPath.section equal to 1 and indexPath.row equal to 0

Comment: thats great thanks but please may you write the code in full using the objects that i have used.

Comment: Sorry, afraid not.  There should be enough here to figure it out.  Take a look at a couple UITableView tutorials if you need to understand the basics of table programming.