# How To Implement Multiple Sections In UITableView for details?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone UITableView Sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445666/iphone-uitableview-sections)

I'm now learning UITableView class on iOS development,How can i implement multiple sections in UITableView for details?Big Thanks!

Comment: -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView*)tableView{
    return 1 or any number of sections you want;
}

Comment: This questions has been asked multiple times. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445666/iphone-uitableview-sections

Answer (score 0):

Return proper value from below delegate method of `UITableViewDataSource`.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://clingingtoideas.blogspot.in/2011/02/uitableview-how-to-part-3-multiple.html)

And yes, read all the other parts as well for a great set of tutorials on UITableView

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use the tableview delegate method

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
    NSInteger iSectionCount = 1;

    return iSectionCount;
}
```

or simply just

```
return 1;//For 1 section
```

inside the delegate method

Answer (score 0):

To return a single section do this:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return 1;
    }
```